Need Help with Ubuntu Desktop Entry launcher
I'm testing an kivymd python application and have discovered several compatibility issues with the python packager and kivymd.
So now I'm relegated to executing the kivymd application manually with python3.  My launcher for the most part works but it's showing the python icon on the favourites section
and python 3.10 in the activities which I don't want.
I want the my icon appearing on favourites and my application name appearing in activities when the app runs. (ubuntu 22.04 desktop)
Launcher:
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=CandoApp
Comment=Service Application
Icon=/home/weave/CandoApp/cando.png
Exec=python3 /home/weave/CandoApp/main.py
Path=/home/weave/CandoApp
Terminal=false
Categories=Application
StartupNotifiy=true

Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Please edit the question and add the version of Ubuntu that you are using.

This question is similar to: How to add launcher icon for python script?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I'm basically doing the same thing with my code although I'm not creating a desktop shortcut.  The result is the same for me, with python executing first the icon and application title sets with that and disregards the launcher settings.
